# if one line has 2 same words, change the second word to 'jinx' using sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

Ex: My only goal is to score a goal in the match

`My only goal is to score a jinx in the match`

There should be a word or more between both words.

Comment: think so it will help you. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: If you want to pass you gotta go to class. Don't skip and then dump homework problems here. You are expected to make an effort. Also see [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow).

Comment: @jww I'm missing a close vote in that case

Comment: @hek2mgl - Yeah, I'm out of close votes too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "My only goal is to score a goal in the match" | \
  sed -r 's/(\b\w+\b)(.*\w+.*)\1/\1\2jinx/g'
My only goal is to score a jinx in the match
```

- `-r` activates extended [posix regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). Note: With basic posix regex you will have to escape parentheses like:  `\(....\)` and the `+` operator doesn't exist
- `(\b\w+\b)` matches a word
- `(.*\w+.*)` captures everything in between
- `\1` matches the first parentheses and `\2` matches the second
- `g` stands for global, without this it will only change the first match

So, `(\b\w+\b)(.*\w+.*)\1/` will find a line with a same word appears twice

then `\1\2jinx` will replace the second occurrence of `\1` with jinx

Comment: It can be rewritten without `-r`, using `BRE`, as `... | sed 's/\(\<.*\>\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2jinx/g'`. Do you know if it is compliant with Basic Regular Expressions from Open Group issue 7 edition 2018? there https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03

Comment: @Jayjargot I just started learning sed, and I didn't know that I could use `<>`to simplify the code. would `... | sed -r 's/(<.*>)(.*)\1/\1\2jinx/g'` work as same? I think that using `-r` gives more readability. Thanks for letting me know Jay. I will definitely give it a read.